# any ready made source code available for intranet (lan) messenger

Tags: intranet, lan

Is there any open source code or free software is available for intranet (Lan) messenger near to http://messenger.softros.com/

Comment: http://messenger.softros.com/

Comment: net send anil_mane yeah, search yourself.

Answer (score 0):

if u want some opensource implementation of Intranet messenger

look at BSD Licensed **[Ipmsg](http://www.ipmsg.org/ipmsg-beta.html)**

Comment: this is good one but bit confusing. Its not very much user friendly like http://messenger.softros.com/